# Jquery Error in Joomla site

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

I am facing jquery errors on my joomla site in which i am using virtue mart but i am loading a jquery from jqueryLoadPlugin, to avoid jquery conflicts & disable virtue mart jquery it works good but when i enable scrollers it again giving me errors.

below i have mentioned the links of the pages, on which i am getting a jquery error for scrollers. kindly guide me what i have to do this to avoid this conflict.
`Jquery.noconflict();` is already called on the page.

please need your help:(

**Links:**

(on the tabs, when you click on the LAtest Projects you will get an slider which stucks.)

http://ple-intl.com/NewUpgrade/

---

(I call module here in the article it does'not works an where)

http://ple-intl.com/NewUpgrade/index.php/service.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things you can try to get this working.

1. Be sure your script is being pulled into the page, one way to check is by using the 'sources' tab in the Chrome Debugger and searching for the file else in the html head section
2. Be sure that you've included the other script after you've included jQuery, as it is most certainly dependant upon that.
3. Check whether jQuery is included properly and once only.
4. Watch out for jQuery conflicts. There is some other library which is overridding $, so your code is not working because $ is not an alias for jQuery anymore. You can use `jQuery.noConflict()` to avoid conflicts with other libraries on the page which use the same variable $.

Try using [jQuery Easy](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/performance/jquery-scripts/18327) rather.